# Bipartite version of Hamming bound (two families of codewords with large Hamming distance)?

Tags: co.combinatorics, it.information-theory, entropy, coding-theory, hamming-distance

**Update:** In light of Fedor Petrov's answer, I added an additional requirement that all strings in $A$ and $B$ have Hamming weight *exactly* $n/2$, which hopefully makes the question more interesting.

Without this additional requirement on the Hamming weight, as Fedor Petrov pointed out, we can let $A$ contain all strings of Hamming weight $n/2+d/2$ and let $B$ contain all strings of Hamming weight $n/2-d/2$.

**Question:** Let $A,B\subset \{0,1\}^n$ be two subsets of binary strings of length $n$ with equal cardinality (i.e. $|A| = |B|$). Suppose they have the following properties:

1. All strings in $A\cup B$ have Hamming weight *exactly* $n/2$.
2. For any $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, the Hamming distance between $a$ and $b$ is at least $d$ for some $d = o(n)$.

Then, what is the largest possible size of $A$ and $B$?

**My guess:** My guess is something around $2^{n-\Theta(d)}$, which is the bound we get when we require the strings in $A$ to have *pairwise* Hamming distance at least $d$ (see Remark 2 below). However the proof in the pairwise case does not seem to apply here.

**Remark 1:** If the cardinalities of $A$ and $B$ were allowed to be lopsided, then it would be possible to make $A$ contain almost everything in $\{0,1\}^n$. Specifically, we could just let $B$ contain the all-zero string $0^n$, to which almost all strings in $\{0,1\}^n$ have Hamming distance $\Omega(n)$.

**Remark 2:** The answer to the following closely related question is characterized by the [Hamming bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_bound) and [Gilbert–Varshamov bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert%E2%80%93Varshamov_bound):

> What is the maximum possible size of a subset $C\subset \{0,1\}^n$ of
> lengh-$n$ binary strings with *pairwise* Hamming distance at least
> $d$?

By the two bounds mentioned above, the answer is known to be between

$$
\left[\frac{2^n}{\sum_{j=0}^{d-1} \binom{n}{j}}, \frac{2^n}{\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{d-1}{2}} \binom{n}{j}} \right].
$$
Note that this impies that the largest size of $C$ is bounded by $2^{n-{\Theta}(d)}$.

Comment: For Remark 2, I think 'almost completely resolved' is putting it rather strongly: if $d = \delta n$ with $\delta < 1/2$ then the ratios are asymptotically $2^{n(1-h(\delta))}$ and $2^{n(1-h(\delta/2))}$, where $h(p) = H(p,1-p)$ is the binary entropy function. Whether there are asymptotically good codes with rate near to $1-h(\delta/2)$ is arguably the main unsolved problem in coding theory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the Hamming distance between $A$ and $B$ is at least $d$, it yields that $B$ is disjoint from the $(d-1)$-neighborhood of $A$. By isoperimetric inequality for a Boolean cube (Harper's theorem), the smallest $d$-neighborhood of $A$ for a given size $|A|$ is attained when $A$ consists of all points with sum of coordinates at most $T$ and several points with sum of coordinates exactly $T+1$ (for appropriate $T$). In this case $B$ essentially consists of points with sum of coordinates at least $T+d$. Since we want $|A|=|B|$, we should take $T=n/2-d/2$. Then $|A|\sim 2^{n-\Theta(d^2/n)}$ by central limit theorem. This is best possible.

For the updated question, take two Hamming balls of radius $n/2−d/2$ centered in opposite points $(0,...,0,1,...,1)$ and $(1,...,1,0,...,0)$ (each center has weight $n/2$) and leave only points of weight $n/2$ in both balls. This still has the same asymptotics.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You are making a very good point - we can essentially let A and B contain strings of Hamming weights that differ by d, then any a in A and b in B must have Hamming distance at least d. In light of this observation, a more interesting question would be: how large can the size of A and B be if we have the additional requirement that all strings in A,B must have Hamming weights exactly n/2? An answer to this question will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Octopus still the same asymptotics. We take two Hamming balls of radius $n/2-d/2$ centered in opposite points $(0,...,0,1,...,1)$ and $(1,...,1,0,...,0)$ (each center has $n/2$ 0s and 1s) and leave only points of weight $n/2$ in both balls

Comment: You are absolutely right, thank you! This is very helpful!